# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{2z+3e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried using finding $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{2z+3e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d}{dz} z^2\frac{2z+3e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}}$,

But neither of the limits seem to work out to a value. Is there any better way to find the residue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac{e^z-1}z\right)^2&\text{ if }z\ne0\\1&\text{ if }z=0.\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $0$ and the function whose residue you want to compute is $\frac{2z+3e^z}{z^2f(z)}$. If you define$$g(z)=\frac{2z+3e^z}{f(z)},$$then $g$ is an analytic function in the neighborhood of $0$ and so\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{2z+3e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}\right)&=\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{g(z)}{z^2}\right)\\&=g'(0)\\&=\frac{5f(0)-3f'(0)}{f^2(0)}\\&=2,\end{align}since\begin{align}f(z)&=\left(1+\frac z2+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)^2\\&=1+z+\frac7{12}z^2+\cdots,\end{align}which implies that $f(0)=f'(0)=1$.